# Comparing blank varchar variable with int variable

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

In my code I need to compare 2 variables. One variable is of int data type & another is of varchar2 data type.

In order to compare I am using the below code:

```
intVariable == atoi(varcharVariable.arr)
```

The issue is that when the corresponding varchar variable is blank then atoi returns 0 which conflicts with my business logic.

Solution: to alter the condition as below:

```
intVariable == atoi(varcharVariable.arr) && strlen(varcharVariable.arr) != 0
```

Please advise if there is any better/alternate way. Thanks in advance.

Best way:

```
intVariable == atoi(varcharVariable.arr) && varcharVariable.arr[0] != 0x00
```

Comment: `varchar2` is not a valid type in C. I've seen a type by that name in some relational DB systems? Please clarify.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Its a pro*c variable. Anyway it functions mostly in the same way as a char variable for the variable.arr part. In this case you can consider it as a char variable itself.

Comment: so it's just the standard array of `char` you're used to in C? Then I'd leave this other stuff out of the question to avoid confusion and create a good [mcve]

Comment: anyways, I expect you're looking for `strtol()`. This will give you all needed error checking, so you can distinguish between explicit `0`, an empty string or a parsing error (and even a range overflow)

Comment: I have some usage example for `strtol()` in my [beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), end of section 4, maybe it's helpful.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Even with `strtol` if I pass an empty string then it returns 0. correct ?

Comment: Yes, you have to check the length of your input string yourself. Without knowing it, `*endp` isn't much help either. I assumed an empty string is just **one** "error case" you'd like to avoid. In general, only `strtol()` gives you what you need to do **complete** error checking.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yup. Please check my question, I already added that solution, I am looking for alternatives/ better functions. Can you explain why strtol is a better function than atoi ?

Comment: Only with `strtol()`, you don't need `strlen()` for it but just check `endp != input && *endp == 0` after the call. This will also cover other parse problems than an empty string.

Comment: @FelixPalmen This just increases the complexity of my code. I have to first call the function strol() and then use the output endp. strlen looks like a much better option as it covers the checks in the same condition. which other `other parse problems` will i encounter ?.. Because we are 100% sure that the value will either be a number or blank.

Comment: I'm not a fan of these "we are 100% sure" decisions, but then at least don't use `strlen()` for checking for an empty string. Just check whether `str[0]` (or `*str`) is the `NUL` character. Like e.g. `if (!*str) { // str is empty }`. Btw what else: your `int` could overflow. `atoi()` doesn't handle this.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I am 100% sure because the data is being picked from a database with number(4) data type column. Thanks for the alternatives for strlen.

Comment: So the question you actually wanted to ask is: **how to quickly check if a null-terminated string is empty**?

Comment: @Groo If there is no other function doing the combined work faster then yes I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Way:

```
intVariable == atoi(varcharVariable.arr) && varcharVariable.arr[0] != 0x00
```